Python async sleep question ordering of execution
Hello I have a quesiton while I'm working through some tutorial on asyncio as given below:
import asyncio
async def task_coroutine():
    print('start executing task')
    await asyncio.sleep(1.0)
    print('done waiting in task')
    raise Exception('error in task')
    return 99

async def main():
    print('main started')
    task = asyncio.create_task(task_coroutine())
    await asyncio.sleep(1.1)
    print('done waiting in main')
    try:
        value = task.result()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    print('end of main')
asyncio.run(main())


as I expected, the result is
main started
start executing task
done waiting in task
done waiting in main
error in task
end of main

because when the task suspend, the main is still sleeping and it switches back to task to throw.
I have been playing around a bit by changing the sleep time of main to 0.1 (1.1 before) and the result is also as I expected
main started
start executing task
done waiting in main
Result is not set.
end of main

since the main trying to collect result of task before it's done so it throws "Result is not set"
However, when I set the sleep time of main to 1.0000000001, it gives:
main started
start executing task
done waiting in main
Result is not set.
end of main
done waiting in task

Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-2' coro=<task_coroutine() done, defined at /Users/user/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/PyCharm2024.1/scratches/scratch.py:3> exception=Exception('error in task')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/charlielao/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/PyCharm2024.1/scratches/scratch.py", line 7, in task_coroutine
    raise Exception('error in task')
Exception: error in task

I don't quite understand why it prints "done waiting in task" at the end after main finishes where it didn't in the 0.1 case, why is there explicit error in this case, what was the exact ordering of events?

I don't know why it causes this error, but the obvious difference is that main's sleep ends right after the tasks's sleep, rather than while the task is still sleeping. But before the task is able to go to the next statement.

FYI A time interval of 1.0000000001 seconds differs from a time interval of 1.0 seconds by one-tenth of a nanosecond.  If your CPU is running at 5 GHz, that is only 0.1 nanoseconds is less than the amount of time it takes to execute a single primitive instruction.  There is no way you can expect those two time intervals to be different in the real world.

The long and short of it is that asyncio.run() continues to run tasks after your main() coroutine finishes. This is to give other tasks a chance to terminate gracefully, rather than to be left in some unknown state. Since the difference in durations between your sleeps is so small, this means the await statement in your child tasks finishes normally. As a result, the child task is instead able to finish by raising your custom exception.
Detail
When the function asyncio.run() finishes running the coroutine that it was passed, it performs some post clean up steps. One of these steps is to call cancel() on each pending task and then run the event loop until each of those tasks has finished. When a task is cancelled a CancelledError is raised at the next pending await statement of the task. This causes well behaved tasks to terminate quickly.
Timings
The difference in the durations of your sleeps is so small, that while the sleep() is still pending when you call task.result(), it is done by the time the event loop gets around to cancelling pending tasks. What this means in practice is that the event loop processes the event that signals the end of the sleep coroutine before it gets a chance to cancel the sleep coroutine. This means a CancelledError cannot be raised by the sleep() coroutine. As there are no further await statements in the task there is no opportunity to raise a CancelledError. Instead the execution of your task continues until it reaches your raise statement. This statement causes your task to terminate with an exception. It is considered a bug if any task terminates with an exception that is not CancelledError, and that exception is never retrieved. As such, the event loop reports this unhandled exception.

A related tip: if someone wants to do own tests, replacing asyncio.run(...) with asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main()) will run main without doing any cleanup afterwards.

Thanks! I see so it's the clean up that finishes up the coroutine, and in the 0.1 case it won't do that since when the main one ends the task just get cancelled as it's not yet finished awaitng.

@VPfB it seems to give the same result in either case? (i.e. finishing up the task after the main finishes)

@charlielao Could be it produces the same output. I did not try. But I now checked that a task still running after main() has finished won't get cancelled (contrary to when using run), so there is a difference. It just probably does not manifest itself in this case.

You say, "The long and short of it is that asyncio.run() continues to run tasks after your main() coroutine finishes." But asyncio.run closes the event loop as soon as the coroutine it is executing returns and so any tasks that have been created but not completed will never complete. See this demo.

@VPfB Using loop.run_until_complete does not allow running but uncompleted tasks to finish. See this demo.

@Booboo What's the purpose of the demo? Did I say something incorrect in my comments?

@VPfB I thought you were implying that you could use run_until_complete, which does not automatically close the event loop, and that would allow running tasks to complete.

@Booboo I'm sorry for such misunderstanding. I proposed it just for investigating the issue - run is with cleanup, run_until_complete is without a cleanup. (Of course, normally you want to use the asyncio.run).
